# Calculating expectation and variance for having rolled 1 and 6 twice out of rolling a die 12 times

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

First i have calculated the probability to get each possible number $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ twice from $12$ rolls ($A$). We have:

$$Pr[A]=\frac{\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}}{6^{12}}.$$

Then there are 2 random variables:

- $X$-number of times that $1$ was received, and
- $Y$-number of times that $6$ was received.

Before calculating $E(X),Var(X),E(Y),Var(Y)$ i'm uncertain of how i should calculate the probabilities of X and Y

Comment: Both $X$ and $Y$ are binomially distributed. The expectation will be $E(X)=E(Y)=np = 12\cdot \dfrac{1}{6} = 2$ and the variance will be $V(X)=V(Y)=np(1-p) = 12\cdot \dfrac{1}{6}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{6}\right) = \dfrac{5}{3}$.

Comment: Note that your calculation is that you will get exactly two of each of the numbers. It does not account for the possibility that you will get 2 eight times, 1 twice, and 6 twice.

Comment: The probability of getting exactly two 1's and two 6's among 12 rolls: $$\dbinom{12}{4}\dbinom{4}{2}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^4\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^8$$

Comment: What will be the probability if i wanted to just get one of either the two in the 12 rolls ?

Comment: If you want either a 1 or a 6, find the probability that for all 12 rolls you get neither and take the compliment: $$1-\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{12} \approx 99.23\%$$

Comment: If you want at least two 1's or at least two 6's, then the probability is a bit more complicated. Now, you have four cases to check: no 1s and no 6s, one 1 and no 6s, no 1s and one 6, or one of each (as in each case, you do not have at least two of one of them. This is given by: $$1-\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{12}-2\dbinom{12}{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^1\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{11}-\dbinom{12}{2}\dbinom{2}{1}\left(\dfrac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^{10} \approx 88.24\%$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Pr(X=x,Y=y)$ is the probability of getting $x$ throws equal to $1$ and $y$ throws equal to $6$.

Here, to calculate we can use the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), simplifying things to just refer to $1$'s, $6$'s, and "Others" where we don't bother breaking the "Others" category down further into each of the different numbers.

Applying the formula (*which should be self-evident how it works*) you get the probability is:

$$Pr(X=x,Y=y) = \binom{12}{x,y,(12-x-y)}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^x\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^y\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{12-x-y}$$

So, the probability of getting exactly two $1$'s and exactly two $6$'s is going to be:

$$Pr(X=2,Y=2)=\frac{12!}{2!2!8!}\cdot \frac{4^8}{6^{12}}$$

As for calculating other metrics of the random variables $X,Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ represent the total number of $1$'s and $6$'s thrown respectively, @Vizag's hint is a good one, representing them each as sums of indicator random variables.

It should be clear that $Pr(X_i = 1) = \frac{1}{6}$, that $Pr(X_i,X_j) = \frac{1}{36}$, that $Pr(X_i,Y_i)=0$ and that $Pr(X_i,Y_j)=\frac{1}{36}$ for $i\neq j$.

Armed with this knowledge and remembering that expectation is linear so you can break apart an expectation of a sum as a sum of expectations, it should be clear how to calculate $E[X^2]$ and $E[XY]$ etc... to complete the later parts of the problem.

Comment: Just to validate $E[X_{i}] = \sum_{i=1}^{12} i*Pr[X_i]=\frac{78}{36}$ ?

Comment: @user3133165 There are a few things wrong with that.  Most importantly, there is no reason to multiply by $i$ here.  That is the whole point of working with indicator random variables.  If the only possible values a random variable can take are zero or one, then $E[I]=Pr(I=1)$.  So, you have $E[X] = E[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{12}X_i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{12}E[X_i]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{12}Pr(X_i=1)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{12}\frac{1}{6}=2$

Comment: And if i aim to calculate $E(XY)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $X$ and $Y$ like this (which greatly simplifies things).

Define an indicator variable $X_i$ such that $X_i = 1$ if we saw a $1$ on the $i^{th}$ throw and $0$ otherwise. Now convince yourself that,

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{12} X_i$$

Similarly define indicator variable $Y_i$ such that $Y_i = 1$ if we saw a $6$ on the $i^{th}$ throw and $0$ otherwise.

Now note that:

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{12} E[X_i], \quad \text{ By Linearity of expectations}$$

$$Var(X) = \sum_{i=1}^{12} Var(X_i), \quad \text { Because $X_i$'s are independent}$$

Comment: I will try but i haven't used this method before , would you kindly go on?. I didn't have to calculate the probability of getting a number twice ?

Comment: @user3133165 what are you wanting to calculate?  The random variables $X,Y$ and their expected value, variance, and covariance etc?  Or are you wanting to calculate the probability of very specifically $Pr(X=2,Y=2)$, i.e. getting exactly two 1's and two 6's?  These are two very different problems.  Vizag's hint here leads you to being able to find things about the variables $X,Y$ and calculating expected value, variance etc..., but is not necessarily the easiest way to think about how to find $Pr(X=2,Y=2)$.

Comment: Can you now understand how to calculate expectation and variance for $X$ and $Y$?